# Is it possible to use System.Type as static parameter in F# type provider?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I was wondering is it possible to use System.Type as the static parameter in F# type provider, so that I can write something like:

```
type HelperType = HelperProvider<typeof<int>>
```

The idea is, is it possible to let type provider generating some helper type based on some .NET type.

Comment: why not "type HelperType = HelperProvider<int>"? I believe that it works the same as other .net languages in that respect.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens Thanks for your reply, I did a test, not work. I post it later.

Comment: here is the code I added:

        let helperProvider =
        let ty = ProvidedTypeDefinition(thisAssembly, providedNamespace, "GPUHelperProvider", Some typeof<obj>, IsErased = false)
        let parameters = ProvidedStaticParameter("Namespaces", typeof<string>) :: ProvidedStaticParameter("Test", typeof<Type>) :: []
        ty.DefineStaticParameters(parameters, generateHelper)
        ty

and then in the code I use: `

[<Literal>]
let namespaces = "TestData.MyGPUTypes.Base;TestData.MyGPUTypes.Derived"

type GPUHelper = Alea.TypeProviders.GPUHelperProvider<namespaces, int>

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens uhmm, cannot write code, just a short feedback then. I used `ProvidedStaticParameter("Test", typeof<Type>)`, and then I use `Provider<int>`, the error is: Script.fsx(12,67): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    System.Type
but here has type
    'a -> int

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, type provider parameters can only be of primitive types (like `int` and `string`). The best you can do is to take the type name as a string:

```
type HelperType = HelperProvider<"int">
```

This will do the trick for primitive (and standard types), but it won't work for types that are defined earlier in the file (or in the project) where you're using the type provider.

As far as I know, this is definitely something that the F# team has been looking into - it would allow some interesting meta-programming applications. The main focus for now has been on data access, so this has not been such a priority (out o curiosity, what application do you have in mind?)

By the way - passing types as parameters can cause some interesting tricky questions. For example, how would the compiler handle something like this:

```
type A = MyProvider<B>
and B = MyProvider<A>
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas, the application I want to do is make a helper type from an existed type. In GPU application (with Alea.cuBase), we want to do some transposing for data before we send them into GPU memory, so it would be good if we can generate some helper types and methods based on existed types. Well, I already uses another method, by putting namespaces in the parameter, and then load the assemblies from the TypeProviderConfig.ReferencedAssemblies, if you have interesting, here is the source code: https://github.com/soloman817/Alea.TypeProviders/blob/master/src/GPUHelperProvider/Provider.fs

Comment: and yes forward declaring is a problem. I also noticed when implementing that I can only use the types from referenced assemblies, not the type that is defined before calling type provider.

Comment: @TomasPetricek Do you know if passing types as parameters to type providers is still something the team is considering? The use case is to have the type provider generate the codebehind for a GUI designer

Comment: Given a record type ``Rec``, I'd like to be able to provide type ``Partial<typeof<Rec> >``, which would have the same fields as ``Rec``, except all of them would be optional (or optional optional, if they were already optional). I would use this to represent potentially incomplete data sets, JSON types where each member may or may not be null, etc.

Comment: 10 years later, I'm looking for a way to do something similar and coming up short.  I'd like to do some pre-compilation step to generate code to serialize some network messages types in a specific way so as to avoid the hit from doing runtime reflection.

So far I've looked into FSharp.Reflection + FSC (still requires reflection at the end of the day), Myriad (dead project, victim of bitrot), Type Providers, and all have at least one deal-breaking limitation.

FsPickler is next, but I'm not hopeful.  I might have to fall back to C♯ + source generators.