# Is it possible to use arrays as static parameters in F# type providers?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I want to create a type provider with a static parameter that is an array. I thought this might work if the array was of another primitive type (int, string etc), but this seems not to work.

As a motivating use-case, this would, for example, allow specifying header names when using a CSV type provider for .csv files without a header row.

Comment: I don't know if that would work, but you could always use a json string to specify that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779413/is-it-possible-to-use-system-type-as-static-parameter-in-f-type-provider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only primitive types can be used as type provider parameters.  The [current json type provider gets around that by using a comma separated list of parameters as a string.](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html)